# Screen Rotaton for LineageOS Android Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, rotation, screen

I installed LineageOS on my raspberrypi 3B, and had a touchscreen monitor attached. However, I need the screen and touchscreen rotated 90 degrees. The first try I made was to use apps to rotate the screen, and all of them resulted in a portrait mode that was still in landscape (see the image below to understand what I mean)

[image]

Next, I tried using ssh and going into the android filesystem into /boot/config.txt and adding `lcd_rotate=1` and `display_rotate=1`, both of which didn't make any differences. Do any of you have any idea how to rotate this screen 90 degrees (filling the entire screen)? I am using a Lebula touchscreen for pi (it is found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VNX4ZWY)).

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know if you've seen: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/multi_display/displays#windows

Comment: @MorrisonChang I tried that, and added android:resizeableActivity="false", as well as android:screenOrientation="portrait" to all my activities, and got the same output... I think the android thinks the screen orientation can only be landscape, which is exactly what I am trying to change...